# Transfer Arduino values ​to Python using the HC-06 Bluetooth module

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to transfer values ​​from Arduino to Python using the HC-06 Bluetooth module.
I confirmed that the value was transmitted normally through serial communication without using Bluetooth.

Arduino

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial BT(13, 12);
int output_data = 0;

void setup() {
  BT.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (BT.available()) {
    char received_char = BT.read();
    Serial.println(received_char);
  }
  BT.println(output_data++);
  delay(500);
}
```

Pycharm

```
import serial

port = "/dev/cu.HC-06"
ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)

while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        val = ser.readline().decode().strip()
        print(val)
```

I'm trying to transmit a value using Bluetooth, but no value is output from PyCharm and no error occurs. What's the problem?